# variable appearing blank after ajax, but has value within ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

As the title says, I have an ajax function that I am using to call a function that assigns a value to a variable in js from my mysql db.  On success, I can print the echoed data out and it appears in the console fine.  However, calling the variable after the ajax call yields an empty variable.  What is going on?

Code below:

```
request = $.ajax({ 
                        url: "/fans/get_url_tag", 
                        type: "post", success:function(data){url_tag = data; console.log(url_tag); //prints the correct value}, 
                        data: {'fbid': result.id} ,beforeSend: function(data){console.log(data);} 
                    });

//prints nothing
console.log(url_tag)
```

Comment: Because the call is Asynchronous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `console.log` in the callback function.

Comment: The whole point is I want it to have the value after the ajax call, not just in the callback function.

Comment: You will have to wait until the AJAX call is completed the access the variable. The `console.log` that you've placed after the AJAX call is executing before `url_tag` has been given a value. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I guess what can I do to get access to the variable after the ajax call?

Comment: You already do have access to it. Anything that requires the value, however, should be in the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the scope is wrong.
Maybe just declare it before your $.ajax call:

```
var url_tag;
request = $.ajax({ 
                    url: "/fans/get_url_tag", 
                    type: "post", success:function(data){url_tag = data; console.log(url_tag);}, 
                    data: {'fbid': result.id} ,beforeSend: function(data){console.log(data);} 
                });

console.log(url_tag); //Should print the same value
```

Comment: Neel is right, the ajax call is async so when you run the 2nd console.log call the request has not completed yet. So it's not a matter of scope it's a matter of timing. The callback that is executed when the request completes will set the variable and any code run AFTER that will have access to the variable and its set value.